# What is the frequency of each of the moving electrons in a DC current?

Tags: electricity, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, frequency, vibrations

I know that the DC current has 0 frequency. But what about each individual moving electron that makes up that DC current? Of course there has to be a frequency as all moving electrons are vibrating at some frequency (no matter where they are). Just not sure what it would be...

Comment: Why must all electrons be vibrating?

Comment: Electrons in DC current move randomly within the drift, therefore they would be vibrating and have a frequency.

Comment: random motion is not the same (necessarily) as vibration...

Answer (score 1):

DC current is organized as following: positive potential applied to one end of the wire, negative potential applied to the other. Electrons move from one end to another with some speed.

If you have one electron in vacuum and electric field from A to B, then there will be force acting upon that electron due to $F=eE$. Movement should happen along line between A and B.

Same happens in simple model of wire with DC. Everything else will be additional effects, such as: thermal fluctuations, interaction of electrons with the metal, interaction of electrons with other electrons and magnetic fields

Comment: aandreev -- Thank you. But what would be the vibrational frequency of a moving electron in a DC wire?

Comment: If you model electrons in wire as an ideal gas, you'll find that there is no particular frequency of vibration. Mainly because brownian motion is not oscillatory.